# Github workflow can not authenticate when trying to use a private repo as a crate

Tags: rust, ssh, continuous-integration, github-actions, rust-cargo

I am trying to use a github repo as a "private crate" and have been following [this resource](https://rpadovani.com/private-rust-crates). I have set up my `cargo.toml` accordingly.

```yaml
[package]
name = "xyz"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
abc = { git = "ssh://git@github.com/org/repo", tag = "0.1.0" }
```

I have set up SSH authentication locally and everything works fine when building the project on my computer. However, when I push my project, CI fails with the following error (repo/org names have been changed to abc or xyz).

```
/home/runner/.cargo/bin/cargo check
    Updating crates.io index
    Updating git repository `ssh://git@github.com/repo/abc.git`
error: failed to get `abc` as a dependency of package `xyz v0.1.0 (/home/runner/work/xyz/xyz)`
Error: failed to get `abc` as a dependency of package `xyz v0.1.0 (/home/runner/work/xyz/xyz)`
Caused by:
  failed to load source for dependency `abc`

Caused by:
  Unable to update ssh://git@github.com/org/abc.git?tag=0.1.0#hash

Caused by:
  failed to clone into: /home/runner/.cargo/git/db/abc-commithash

Caused by:
  failed to authenticate when downloading repository: https://***@github.com/org/abc-rs.git

  * attempted to find username/password via git's `credential.helper` support, but failed

  if the git CLI succeeds then `net.git-fetch-with-cli` may help here
  https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#netgit-fetch-with-cli

Caused by:
  failed to acquire username/password from local configuration
Error: The process '/home/runner/.cargo/bin/cargo' failed with exit code 101
```

My current workflow looks like this:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - development
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
      - development

name: Continuous integration

jobs:
  check:
    name: Check
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Configure Git for HTTPS
        run: |
          git config --global credential.helper store
          cat > ~/.git-credentials <<- EOM
          https://${{ secrets.CI_TOKEN }}@github.com
          EOM
          git config --global url."https://${{ secrets.CI_TOKEN }}@github.com".insteadOf ssh://git@github.com
      
          
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions-rs/toolchain@v1
        with:
          profile: minimal
          toolchain: stable
          override: true
      - uses: actions-rs/cargo@v1
        with:
          command: check
```

I have created a token with full permissions. Can anyone spot what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try using `git config --global url."https://${{ secrets.CI_TOKEN }}@github.com".insteadOf git@github.com` without the `ssh://` in the workflow file? (i'm using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/taoyuan/bfa3ff87e4b5611b5cbe) as reference)